# Centering 2 images in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, pug

I'm still learning Bootstrap and I want to center 2 images in Bootstrap.

My code is here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBmeZL?editors=100

Jade:

```
.container
  .row
    .col-sm-12.text-center
      img(alt="wyzelweimarski" src="http://placehold.it/1050x200")

hr

.containter
  .row
    .col-sm-6
      figure.text-center
        img.img-thumbnail(alt="wyzelweimarski" src="http://placehold.it/500x300")
        figcaption
          button.btn.btn-success(type="button") Click
    .col-sm-6
      figure.text-center
        img.img-thumbnail(alt="wyzelweimarski" src="http://placehold.it/500x300")
        figcaption
          button.btn.btn-success(type="button") Click
```

Sass:

```
img
  max-width: 100%
  padding-top: 10px

hr
  visibility: hidden

figcaption
  padding-top: 10px
  padding-bottom: 10px
```

This is what I have and what I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeCzI.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your second grouping has a mispelled class name. `containter` should be `container`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emMEZR?editors=100